# Alternative for regex function

Tags: python, regex, list, indexing, append

Here is my code,

```
import re
with open('newfiles.txt') as f:
   k = f.read()
p = re.compile(r'\w+|[^\w\-\s]')
originaltext = p.findall(k)
uniquelist = []
for word in originaltext:
   if word not in uniquelist:
       uniquelist.append(word)
indexes = ' '.join(str(uniquelist.index(word)+1) for word in originaltext)
print('Here are the index positions of the text file : ' + indexes)
```

It takes a text file (a couple of random sentences with punctuation) and then outputs each of the positions of where each word/punctuation occurs. If something repeats twice then the first occurred position is displayed. Punctuation is treated as an individual word in this program.

I was trying to play with the code and then was trying to simplify it. Using the regex function I only need two lines of code to find and separate the words and punctuation and is thus extremely efficient. But, does anyone know a less complex and simpler way to do this rather than using regex? Mind if i ask, if you do answer, please do not change other parts of the code, just another way of doing the same function (to display the indexes of the words) instead of using regex. Obviously it's going to be longer so that does not matter.

**newfiles.txt**

```
Parkour, also known as freerunning, is a relatively new sport founded by Sebastian Foucan, who showed off his skills in the James Bond movie "Casino Royale", which was released in 2006. Parkour is running, jumping over obstacles, or climbing over buildings and walls.
It is daring, breathtaking and at times terrifying, and now it is also an official sport in the UK, making the UK the first country in the world to recognise it. This means that people can teach parkour in schools.
Some people are worried about the sport being too dangerous, but the founder says that it is as safe as any sport, comparing to rugby, wrestling, surfing or climbing, but, - if you do not do it in the right way, you can get hurt.
```

**Output**

```
Here are the index positions of the text file : 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 2 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 26 2 29 30 31 21 32 33 1 7 34 2 35 36 37 2 38 39 36 40 41 42 33 43 7 44 2 45 41 46 47 48 2 41 49 50 7 3 51 52 11 21 22 53 2 54 22 53 22 55 56 21 22 57 58 59 50 33 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 21 67 33 68 63 69 70 71 22 11 72 73 74 2 75 22 76 77 62 50 7 5 78 5 79 11 2 80 58 81 2 82 2 83 38 39 2 75 2 84 85 86 87 86 50 21 22 88 89 2 85 64 90 91 33
```

Thank you

Comment: please provide some sample data from `newfiles.txt`.

Comment: Include the current input and output.

Comment: @ppasler Check the question - i have added it

Comment: @MYGz Check the question - its been added

Comment: @ppasler Don't mark it as a quote. Code formatting is identical to actual format.

Comment: @MYGz I think you can read it better as quote, but nevermind :)

Comment: @ppasler I agree it is better read as a quote. But when you write the code, it's better to see how the lines are separated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you against regex? It's by far the most efficient means of tackling this problem, and it's arguably "simpler" than a non-regex solution.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi As i mentioned before, I was playing with the code, i was just curios to know different means to approaching the same function

Comment: Re efficiency, `word not in uniquelist` and `uniquelilst.index()` seem by far bigger efficiency drains than the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really hard to write "readable code". Still I don't see why to do this, but it was a nice challenge :) I couldn't help myself and changed your way of building a unique set (using OrderedDict):

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
import string
from numpy.testing.utils import assert_array_equal

k = '''Parkour, also known as freerunning, is a relatively new sport founded by Sebastian Foucan, who showed off his skills in the James Bond movie "Casino Royale", which was released in 2006. Parkour is running, jumping over obstacles, or climbing over buildings and walls.
It is daring, breathtaking and at times terrifying, and now it is also an official sport in the UK, making the UK the first country in the world to recognise it. This means that people can teach parkour in schools.
Some people are worried about the sport being too dangerous, but the founder says that it is as safe as any sport, comparing to rugby, wrestling, surfing or climbing, but, - if you do not do it in the right way, you can get hurt.'''

# the one you know
p = re.compile(r'\w+|[^\w\-\s]')
originaltext = p.findall(k)
uniquelist = []
for word in originaltext:
   if word not in uniquelist:
       uniquelist.append(word)
indexes = ' '.join(str(uniquelist.index(word)+1) for word in originaltext)


# the 'readable one'
w = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + "0123456789" 
originaltext2 = []
word = ""
for char in k:
    if char in " -\t\n\r\f\v":
        if word != "":
            originaltext2.append(word)
        word = ""
    elif char not in w:
        if word != "":
            originaltext2.append(word)
        originaltext2.append(char)
        word = ""
    else:
        word += char

uniquelist2 = OrderedDict.fromkeys(originaltext2).keys()
indexes2 = ' '.join(str(uniquelist2.index(word)+1) for word in originaltext2)

# same output
assert_array_equal(indexes, indexes2)
```